# Android: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/zza;

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I can't stop getting this error every time, and I don't know what caused it and how I can solve it:

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/zza;
```

I think it may have to do with `google-services`, but I'm not entirely sure.

`app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 10173
        versionName "4.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Fixes "Duplicate files copied in APK" build bug
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Pushy SDK
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'

    compile 'me.pushy:sdk:1.0.43'

    // AppCompat v7 Dependency
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'
    // Google Play Services Dependencies
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

    // All .jar files in ./libs
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912079/com-android-dex-dexindexoverflowexception-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536-i/36912449 . The problem is that you have all of google play services in your dependencies, with this line: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'` . Just use the individual libraries that your app needs.

Comment: I updated the code in the question and now another error is received: "Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/zza;"

Comment: You're using an old version of `places`, which has been deprecated.  update places to the new places library: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Answer (score 0):

If your app has more than 65535 methods, you need to enable the [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) format for your app.

This can be caused by having lots of dependencies in your project.

Comment: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/location/places/zza; getting this error

Comment: @redalert I'm not sure about that at the moment. But there must be a solution. Google might help.